# CPanel SQL "super" user on a shared host

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, hosting, cpanel

I have a shared hosting account which I need an SQL user which can access all the databases I created. My website creates a new SQL database for each new registered user, now my website can't access the new databases because now I can only grant privileges threw the CPanel is there a way around that? and if not what should I ask from my hosting provider?

Thanks!

Comment: Please just describe the issue above with your provider. Please explain it steps by steps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created database from Cpanel with "Database Wizard" and also created user and grant all privileges then you can access that database entering correct info in your code. Like database name, database user and password in your website code.